# HTML CSS putting a unknown tab before element

Tags: html, css

I am facing a strange problem. I prepared an html page in jsfiddle and putting same code in one html in below method.

```
<html>
<style>
   jsfiddle css
</style>
   jsfiddle html code
</html>
```

my jsfiddle:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3b6suLv/4/)

having this as `test.html` and opening in chrome. It shows perfect in jsfiddle but shows an extra tab (or maybe some whitespaces) before the second item ("Comments:") in div. I am not able to figure out the reason. Please help.

Comment: This is a little bit problematic as you don't have any reproducible issue.  However, are you using any [CSS resets](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)?  If not, it is possible you are running into the the browser's built-in stylesheet...

Comment: You should edit the code from the fiddle directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to enhance your code a little to get fields show up they way you desire.

```
<div class="dtl">
    <div>
         <b>&nbsp;Name:</b><span class="input"><input class="inputtxt" type="text"></span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div>
         <b>&nbsp;Comments:</b><span class="input"><input class="inputtxt" type="text"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3b6suLv/20/)

Comment: Thanks @nirvana74v.  it worked !!  it seems style="clear:both;" did the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes to your CSS and see if it solves the problem:

```
/* add these lines */
label {
  display:block;
  float: left;
}

span.input {
  display: block;
  float:right; /* ADD THIS LINE */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

and then:

```
span > input.inputtxt{ /* CHANGE THIS AS WELL */ width: 290px; height:12px; border:none;}
```

And apply a `<label></label>` for each input.

```
<div class="dtl">
    <b><label>Name:</label></b>
    <span class="input"><input class="inputtxt" type="text" /></span>

    <b><label>Comments:</label></b>
    <span class="input"><input class="inputtxt" type="text" /></span>
</div>
```

It seems to get better in the JSFiddle. Try it out.
Check the results: [JSFiddle Result](http://jsfiddle.net/a3b6suLv/19/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this small reset to remove any built-in styles from the browser. This removed any and all built-in spacing in your fiddle.

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box }
```

Comment: I added the line on top of all css in <style> but it didn't work

Comment: What extra whitespace are you talking about here?

Comment: when i put the same code in an html page. it shows white spaces before second element in div

Comment: Screenshot of that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the jsfiddle has `line-height:normal` as default and the local html has `line-height:1`.

The tab comes from the different heights of the input elements, and since you are floating, the second label floats after the first horizontally because there is still vertical space before a new line is needed.

add `span.input { line:height:1 }` to see consistent results.